# Is there a specific VS Code API to detect if an editor is split and that split screen is active?

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VS Code extension and I need to detect when the editor window is split into multiple panes. Currently, I'm using vscode.window.tabGroups to get the number of active tab groups, and I infer that a split screen is active if there is more than one group. However, this approach has its limitations

1.Is there a more direct VS Code API to determine if the editor is in a split-screen configuration?
2.If there isn't, is my approach the best way to accomplish this? Are there any edge cases I should be aware of?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!.

I'm developing a VS Code extension where I need to track whether the editor is in a split-screen configuration or not. I tried using vscode.window.tabGroups.onDidChangeTabGroups and vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor events to manage this, but I'm running into some issues.

```
let isScreenSplit = false;
let files = [];
let activeTabGroupsCount = 1;

vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor((event) => {
  Some logic here...
});

vscode.window.tabGroups.onDidChangeTabGroups((event) => {
  Some logic here...
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question so it doesn’t read like you started rewriting it from scratch half way through.

Comment: @Kramer Hi kramer, any update on this, does Mark's answer be able to meet your requirements? :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any api for directly detecting whether a file is open in multiple groups.  You would have to test each tab to see if it matches the  active tab in some fashion.  In the code below I test against the `uri.fsPath` for each tab.

```js
const multipleGroups = vscode.window.tabGroups.all.length > 1;

if (multipleGroups) {

    const activeUriPath = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri.fsPath;
    const allTabs = vscode.window.tabGroups.all.flatMap(group => group.tabs);

    const files = allTabs.filter(tab => {
        if (tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputText) return tab.input.uri.fsPath === activeUriPath;
    });

    // if files > 1 then you have the same uri opened in multiple groups
    // splits "in group" are not counted as a split to another, no way to detect if split in group
    console.log(files);
}
```

You see I limited the test to standard text editors with `(tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputText)`, so settings, keyboard shortcuts, previews, custom editors, notebooks would not be considered. You could expand the condition to consider other `tab.input` types if necessary.

---

Here is another approach I like a little better, it should be slightly more performant since it will stop scanning the tabs upon finding the first uri match in a different viewColumn:

```js
const multipleGroups = vscode.window.tabGroups.all.length > 1;
const activeTabColumn = vscode.window.tabGroups.activeTabGroup.viewColumn;
const activeTab = vscode.window.tabGroups.activeTabGroup.activeTab;
const allTabs = vscode.window.tabGroups.all.flatMap(group => group.tabs);

if (multipleGroups) {
    
    const splitFile = allTabs.find(tab => {
        if (tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputText && activeTab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputText)
            return (tab.input.uri.fsPath === activeTab.input.uri.fsPath) && (tab.group.viewColumn !== activeTabColumn);
    });

    // will be undefined if no split of the activeEditor
    console.log(splitFile);
}
```